# How to set UI Theme in Test (Salesforce1)?

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforce1-app

I have code as

```
if(UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()=='Theme4t')
{
    //Some lines
}
```

This code checks if the user is in SF1 app then executes some logic.
How can I cover these lines in test class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to just use a `@TestVisible static Boolean` flag. It's a common, simple control mechanism:

**In your code:**

```
@TestVisible static Boolean isInSalesforce1 = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() == 'Theme4t';

// elsewhere...
if (isInSalesforce1)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

**In your test:**

```
MyClass.isInSalesforce1 = true;

Test.startTest();
    // run conditional logic
Test.stopTest();
```